# Example program crashes on TASM5, why?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have compiled the WAP32 program. This is a example program in the TASM directory.

TASM32.exe wap32.asm
TLINK32.exe wap32.obj

When I start it, it crashes. What's the problem? Maybe my processor? I have AMD Athlon(TM) XP 1700+

On the other hand, Turbo Assembler is a good assembler nowadays for 32-bit programming? I mean, that's not a problem, it has been relased 20 years ago?

Thank you,
Hye

Comment: What is it trying to do there have been quite a few changes in both PC hardware and the Windows API in 20 years.  Which OS are you trying running it on?

Comment: MS Windows XP SP3. So the problem is the example program, not the compiler, right? To tell the truth my main question is the second, so TASM can be used to develop 32-bit programs, or I should searh an another compiler?

Comment: Post the exception and maybe of the ASM code that is running at the time.

Comment: `TASM` should work as long as you're running on an x86 architecture in Windows. When you say "crash" exactly what do you mean? Do your `TASM wap32.asm` or `TLINK32 wap32.obj` commands produce any output of interest? You might, though, want to have a look at MASM32 which is quite popular.

Comment: I forgot to tell, during compiling there were errors:

Error: Unresolved external 'GETMODULEHANDLEA' referenced from module wap32.asm
Error: Unresolved external 'FINDWINDOWA' referenced from module wap32.asm
Error: Unresolved external 'LOADICONA' referenced from module wap32.asm
Error: Unresolved external 'LOADCURSORA' referenced from module wap32.asm

Comment: and so many.

Then, which assembler used nowadays?

Comment: To get rid of that list of unresolved externals, you may need to link against "import32.lib". In alphabetical order, Fasm, Gas, Jwasm, Masm, Nasm, and Yasm would all be newer.

Comment: Aha, thank you. And what about GNU assembler (as), or GoAsm? Are they good?

Comment: I left out Jeremy Gordon's GoAsm! My bad! It's fine AFAIK - I don't think it's as "popular" as the others. Nasm users commonly use his GoLink for 'doze. The GNU assembler, commonly called "Gas" but actually named "as", had a reputation "intended as a back end for gcc and not fit for human consumption" in the old days, but it has improved a lot. Some people don't like AT&T syntax, but it will do ".intel_syntax noprefix" recently (not too well documented). Masm is probably most popular (Windows only), followed by Nasm/Fasm in some order. I like Nasm, but they're all good. Tasm still works.